# How to get all the lines in between partial matches using awk or sed?

Tags: awk, sed

My file looks something like this:

```
>Cluster 0
0   58aa, >5XX8A... at 91.38%
1   58aa, >3LDMA... at 100.00%
2   58aa, >3BTHI... at 96.55%
3   65aa, >1F7ZI... *
4   58aa, >3LDJA... at 100.00%
>Cluster 1
0   57aa, >1ZJDB... at 94.74%
1   58aa, >1AAPA... at 91.38%
2   56aa, >5NX1D... at 92.86%
>Cluster 2
0   60aa, >4ISLB... at 98.33%
1   62aa, >4ISNB... at 95.16%
>Cluster 3
0   59aa, >3BYBA... *
1   59aa, >5ZJ3A... at 100.00%
2   59aa, >3UIRC... at 100.00%
3   57aa, >3D65I... at 100.00%
```

How can I use sed or awk to get the IDs after > (for example: 5XX8A) in between the ">Cluster" ones.
I want to be able to save them separately (in different files). One file per cluster. Or something more parsable like a single file with the IDs right next to the cluster number.

As a first approach doing something like:

```
sed -n '/^\>/,/^\>/p' filename
```

returns the whole file :/

Comment: What do mean by "to get", do you have a desired format?  Currently they are grouped with the header indicating the cluster.  So, it looks like they are in the right format.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was perhaps too general. I have edited it with exactly what I need.

Comment: Do you care for a simple bash solution without sed/awk ?

Comment: Yes that works too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '/^>Cluster /{close(f); f="Cluster."$2; next} {sub(/>/,"",$3); print $3 > f}' file
  
$ head Cluster*
==> Cluster.0 <==
5XX8A...
3LDMA...
3BTHI...
1F7ZI...
3LDJA...

==> Cluster.1 <==
1ZJDB...
1AAPA...
5NX1D...

==> Cluster.2 <==
4ISLB...
4ISNB...

==> Cluster.3 <==
3BYBA...
5ZJ3A...
3UIRC...
3D65I...
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks :) just one question. Why do we need "next" for? What does it do?

Comment: if you remove `next` it will print the header in the file as well.  This way it will skip the rest of script and move on to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -En '/^>(Cluster) /{s//>\1./;:a;x;s/\n(.*)/ echo "\1"/e;x;h;d};s/.*>//;s/ .*//;H;$!d;ba' file
```

Gather up each cluster in the hold space and using the evaluation flag on the substitution command echo the collection to the file name indicated by the first line of the collection.

Alternative method, using sed and piping to sh:

```
sed '/^>Cluster/{s/ /./;h;d};s/..*>//;s/ .*//;G;x;s/>*/>>/;x;s/\n/ /;s/\S*/echo "&"/' file|sh
```

Alternative method, using sed and csplit:

```
sed 's/^..*>//;s/ .*//' file | csplit -szf Cluster -b '.%d' --suppress-matched - '/>Cluster/' '{*}'
```

Manipulate the file into the desired format using sed and then split the file into separate files using csplit.

N.B. This may not replicate the filenames faithfully.